# DataBinding does not work. System.Windows.Data tracing does not give any useful info

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tariffs}" Margin="6">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <custControls:RoundButton Name="TariffButton" Margin="3"
         Content="{Binding TariffName}" Style="{DynamicResource TariffButton}">
           <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                 <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="PickUpTariff">
                   <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding Path=Content, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type custControls:RoundButton}}}" />
                 </cal:ActionMessage>
              </i:EventTrigger>
           </i:Interaction.Triggers>
       </custControls:RoundButton>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Relative source binding works just fine. Content="{Binding TariffName}" works just fint to.

But here is what contained in the Style TariffButton.

```
<Style x:Key="TariffButton" TargetType="customControls:RoundButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChosen, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChosen, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And it does not work! More accurately, it works just once. So the data trigger is invoked only once.

Here is the ViewModel part:

```
 public class DocumentChoiceViewModel:PropertyChangedBase {
    public ObservableCollection<Tariff> Tariffs { get; private set; }

    public DocumentChoiceViewModel() {
        Tariffs = new ObservableCollection<Tariff> {
            new Tariff {IsChosen = true, TariffName = "ПАССАЖИРСКИЙ"},
            new Tariff {IsChosen = false, TariffName = "ЭКСПРЕСС"},
            new Tariff {IsChosen = false, TariffName = "КОМФОРТ"},
            new Tariff {IsChosen = false, TariffName = "ДОП.СК.М-НОГИНСК"}
        };
    }      

    public void PickUpTariff(string tariffName) {
        if (!IsTariffPlanExists(tariffName))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Unexpectable state. User should not be able to choose tariff plan which is not present in Tariffs list");                     
    }        
}

public class Tariff:PropertyChangedBase {
    private bool isChosen;

    public bool IsChosen {
        get { return isChosen; }
        set {
            isChosen = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>IsChosen);
        }
    }

    public string TariffName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first if you have some problems debugging bindings - use a converter as an additional layer where you will see all changes.
And second - set binding mode to be `TwoWay`.

Answer (score 0):

Style Triggers only work with Dependency Properties defined in the TargetType.

Why don't you just make an IsChosenToBackgroundConverter and write this

```
<RoundButton Background="{Binding IsChosen, Converter={StaticResource IsChosenToBackgroundConverter}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful. But now Converter fires only once! As I understand this means that notification is broken, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but you don't need to add a `Trigger` for both `True` *and* `False` conditions:

```
<Style x:Key="TariffButton" TargetType="customControls:RoundButton" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChosen}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```